# Forcing compatibility mode in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, compatibility

I've gone through a few iterations of this but I'm having serious troubles rendering my wordpress site in IE9 properly.

The site is [click here](http://www.dasilvamotorsport.com). Works perfectly in chrome/FF of course.

IE9 native mode will occasionally throw a hard js script error (separate issue I'm looking at) but forcing compatibility mode seems to render it properly.

So now the question, trying to automatically force IE8 compatibility in IE9. From what I've read this should do it:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8" charset="UTF-8" />
```

But it does nothing.

I've tried variations including:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8, chrome=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=IE8">
```

And no joy.

Right now I have the following in the header:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8, chrome=1">
```

If you actually look at the debug in IE8/9 it shows:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE8, chrome=1" charset="UTF-8" <meta=""/>
```

I don't know why/where it injects charset and the stray meta tag. In chrome it shows correctly.

Should the meta have a trailing /? I've tried it both ways and IE still adds that meta to the end.

Any suggestions?

Appreciate the help on this.

Nik

Comment: With what DOCTYPE your page is served?

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

You're missing the closing / on your site, which is causing it to show up as invalid markup in the page source.

Comment: True I fixed that now. So IE=8 or IE=EmulateIE8? This IE business is so incredibly frustrating. :)

Comment: [This](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx) seems to offer a reasonable explanation, looks like they may give the same result but sticking with IE=8 is safer.